# Connecting to a remote MS-SQL Server instance

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc, mssql-jdbc

I am trying to connect to a remote MS-SQL database instance using JDBC.  MS-SQL is running in a remote Windows machine and my JDBC program is running in a linux machine.

```
public class JdbcSQLServerConnection {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        if (args.length != 3) {
            System.out.println("Usage :\njava -jar jarFile.jar url username password");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            String dbURL = args[0];
            String user = args[1];
            String pass = args[2];
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, user, pass);
            if (conn != null) {
                DatabaseMetaData dm = (DatabaseMetaData) conn.getMetaData();
                System.out.println("Driver name: " + dm.getDriverName());
                System.out.println("Driver version: " + dm.getDriverVersion());
                System.out.println("Product name: " + dm.getDatabaseProductName());
                System.out.println("Product version: " + dm.getDatabaseProductVersion());
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (conn != null && !conn.isClosed()) {
                    conn.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

While running the code, I am getting the following exception:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host XX.XXX.XX.XXsqlexpress, port 1433 has failed. Error: null. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.

I am using the driver sqljdbc4.jar. Shown below is my JDBC program.

Comment: Did you verify that "an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port." and did you "Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall."?

Comment: Kayaman, i did telnet 1433.  It is coming as connected to the server.

Comment: Then your connection string is wrong, but since you're not showing it we can't know.

Comment: If your error message truly doesn't have anything between `XX` and `sqlexpress`, then that's why. What is the URL you give? Remember, on a Linux commandline, ``\`` is an escape character, so you need to double it.

Comment: Andreas, I gave url like this : jdbc:sqlserver://XX.XXX.XXX.XX\\sqlexpress username password

Comment: Edit relevant information into your question, don't use comments.

Comment: Try printing the URL before connecting, to see if Java got the right URL.

Comment: Thank you Andreas and Kayaman, I got the solution now.  The URL should be like "jdbc:sqlserver://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX;integratedSecurity=false".  Now I am able to connect to the remote MSSQL instance.